# Google Play app listing shows as "Not Found" when shared on facebook by users

Tags: android, facebook, google-play

Whenever I share the link to my Android game on facebook, it comes up as "Not found". This is a minor inconvenience, however this is also happening for everyone else, and stopping people from sharing links to my app (since they see it as it won't work, rather than just that facebook can't find the info).

I tried sharing a link to Angry Birds, andit works fine.

Steps to produce the error:

1. Copy URL for game listing https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=co.uk.toiletboy.toiletboy
2. Paste into status box on facebook
3. Wait for it to get the info
4. Instead of the app name, it just says "Not found"

I feel like I should get this fixed as soon as I can - is there anything I can do in Google Play settings to get this sorted? Has anyone seen anything like thi before? Please help!

Edit: Worked out the solution myself, o have posted it below.

Comment: seems weird, not sure why its happening though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, turns out this was pretty simple, although not immediately obvious. Facebook last scraped the Google Play website 4 days ago, and at that time, my app hadn't been published. hy they don't retry scraping a page when someone gives them a new URL, I don't know...

For anyone else facing this issue in future, facebook have a tool to "debug" your site, here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

You enter the URL, and get info on when it was last scraped, and what info / images they found. You also get the option to ask them the scrape it again, which I did, and this solved the issue.

Phew!